# how to change validity a signatures

Tags: android, android-studio

I published my application on other stores but google play.

now,I want to publish on google play. google play says:

> You uploaded an APK signed with a certificate that expires too soon.
>   You need to sign your APK with a certificate that expires farther into
>   the future.

I think I have to change `validity(year)`.

should I create new signatures ? or, can I change validity(year) a signatures ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot extend the validity of a certificate. You'll need to generate a new *keystore* file with extended validity and sign the apk for Google Play with that. Google recommends 25 years and above; 30 should suffice.

Make sure you have a backup of your existing certificate too or you may lose access to update your app on your other third party app stores.

Comment: in the future, to update my application, users must uninstall my app and install new app ?

Comment: I have not tried this but I'm pretty sure if one of your users have installed an old version from a different app store and now tries to update to the one available on Google Play, they'll be unable to do so (due to different signatures) and would have to uninstall the old version first.

Comment: If on the other hand, your third party store users keep updating through the same app store and you keep publishing upgrades via the same old signature they'll receive updates without any issues.